# SourceKit Service nightmare

Tags: xcode

My SSK usually takes up 100% of a core and drains battery really quickly.

Each time it does this, I got to Activitiy Monitor, figure out which folder in the ModuleCache it's working on, delete it and then finally force quit SSK, and things return to normal for a little bit, and then the same exact problem returns.

Any advice on this issue?

Comment: You don't think this is rather broad? And rather vague?

Comment: No. And no. Well, maybe. I'm just hoping someone experienced a similar thing and came across a solution.